# configure ngrok as service > permission denied

Tags: permissions, services, systemctl

I have a permissions error while attempting to setup ngrok as a service.

```
$ sudo ngrok service install --config /home/m/snap/ngrok/79/.config/ngrok/ngrok.yml


INFO[08-12|19:11:50] open config file                         path=/home/m/snap/ngrok/79/.config/ngrok/ngrok.yml err="open /home/m/snap/ngrok/79/.config/ngrok/ngrok.yml: permission denied"
INFO[08-12|19:11:50] detect init system                       sys=linux-systemd
CRIT[08-12|19:11:50] install failed                           err="Failed to install ngrok: open /etc/systemd/system/ngrok.service: permission denied"
```

Installed ngrok on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS using snap.

```
sudo snap install ngrok
which ngrok
/snap/bin/ngrok
```

checking ngrok config after install

```
ngrok config check
Valid configuration file at /home/m/snap/ngrok/79/.config/ngrok/ngrok.yml
```

checking permissions of files

```
user@blah:~/f_projs/ngrok_config$ ls -la /snap/bin/ngrok
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Aug  4 16:53 /snap/bin/ngrok -> /usr/bin/snap
user@blah:~/f_projs/ngrok_config$ ls -la /home/user/snap/ngrok/79/.config/ngrok/ngrok.yml
-rw------- 1 m m 167 Aug 12 19:01 /home/user/snap/ngrok/79/.config/ngrok/ngrok.yml
```

- ngrok is owned by root and has permissions lrwxrwxrwx.
- ngrok service install  attempts to create ngrok.service in directory /etc/systemd/system/, this directory is owned by root, root has rwx permissions on this folder.
- ngrok.yml file is owned by user m and has permissions -rw-------
- reading ngrok.yml is not the problem.

still don't understand why I'm experiencing 'permission denied'.

Comment: this is a duplicate question of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73331969/configure-ngrok-as-service-permission-denied  
idk if I should delete the other question as I suspect unix.stackexchange.com is a closer aligned forum.